exclude updating a specific column if the designated value is X
I'm trying to exclude updating a specific column, if the designated value is X (71). this is the code I try to run, but when testing on other numbers like 60, the list_type column get updated with 60 even though it should not.
       //always excldue these columns from getting update
        $columns = array('`fast`', '`foo`', '`list_type`');  
  
        // generel update mechnism
        $columnsForUpdate = array();
        foreach($columns as $column) {
            if($column != '`vid`' && in_array($column, $columnsCommon)) {   //check if column already in both the table
                $columnsForUpdate[] = "`tmp`.{$column} = `fast`.{$column}";
            }
        }

        // dont exclude update of list_type, if designated value is 71
        if (in_array('`list_type`', $columnsCommon)) {
            // Ensure list_type is only updated if it's '71'
            $columnsForUpdate[] = "`tmp`.`list_type` = CASE WHEN `fast`.`list_type` = '71' THEN '71' ELSE `tmp`.`list_type` END";
        }


seems like u need to re-design your database if you need to exclude some of the column

You must add into the query not your CASE expression but the condition WHERE NOT table_to_update.column_name <=> 71.

@Akina that will exclude rows, not the column

@ysth If OP needs to store one column value but update another columns than he'd use according trigger.

So you are updating tmp from fast, but for list_type if the fast value is not 71 you want to leave tmp.list_type unchanged?  Have you done debugging to verify your in_array check is working and columnsForUpdate is set as you expect?

Looks like maybe you need to skip both vid and list_type in the loop

Your description says you want to exclude it if the value is 71, the comment in the code appears to be saying the opposite. Also, we can't see what the resulting statement you assemble based on this, will actually look like. Please add that, and give a proper example of a record for which this goes wrong.

It looks like your problem is that you are unconditionally updating list_type earlier.  Change to this:
        if($column != '`vid`' && $column != '`list_type`' && in_array($column, $columnsCommon)) {   //check if column already in both the table

